# How to check a UIView placed inside of UIImage portion or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiimage, swift4.2

According to my requirement i need to check `UIView` are placed inside of `UIImage` portion or not.Suppose i have `UIImage` of human with cap, here i need to check my view placed inside of cap portion or not.

Could you please guide me to achieve following requirement.

### Example:

```
      ---------------------------------
     |                                |
     |          UIImage               |
     |   --------------------------   |
     |  |   Image portion          |  |
     |  |              ------      |  |
     |  |             | view |     |  |
     |  |              ------      |  |
     |  |                          |  |
     |   --------------------------   |
     |                                |
     |                                |
     --------------------------------
```

Comment: I used this lib for tracking touches on human body parts. 
May be helpful to you https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG

Comment: @RohitWankhede but in my requirement i will place few views in top of UIIageView, while submit i need to check any views out of bounds of that image portion or not.

Comment: I suggest to you use OpenCv to locate the object (that you want to locate), then test if the UIView is located on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the method `contains(_:)` or `intersects(_:)` of `CGRect`.
Your code will look something like

`let imagePortionFrame = CGRect(....) // some rect based on your image view
imagePortionFrame.contains(view.frame)`

You just need to make sure that the coordinates of `imagePortionFrame` and `view.frame` are expressed using the same coordinate system; if not you could use the method `convert(_:to:)`

Reference:

- [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains)
- [intersect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454747-intersects)
- [convert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)

Comment: lannotta here how i need to find image portion from UIImage(Like human have a cap----->i need to find here only cap boundaries)?

Comment: This is a very different problem. If your problem is to found the bounding box of different items in an image you need to look into machine learning and image processing.

Comment: @MarioIannotta it is not different problem just need to convert rect of image view as per aspect ratio of image size otherwise every thing is fine

Answer (score 0):

- import AVFoundation
- Get Rect For image View and Convert rect as per     image size using
  AVMakeRect.
- Check new rect contain UIView frame using contains method of
  coordinate system

Code :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

func containViewInSideImage(imgView:UIImageView,innerView:UIView) -> Bool  {
        let size = imgView.image?.size  // size of image
        let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: size!, insideRect: imgView.frame)  // rect of image portion
        return imageRect.contains(innerView.frame)  // check view is inside image rect
 }
```

Note : Above code will work for aspect-fit property of image view and  Make Sure imageView and view both are belong to same supper view otherwise need to convert rect

Comment: @Justin Kathrotiya According to above code we can  find UIImage portion only, but i am expecting UIImage content portion.

Comment: what is you imageview content type aspect fit , or fill

Comment: Did you want  to find object rect inside image?

Comment: I have a image(Human wearing cap) ,here i need cap boundaries.

Comment: you should check vision Api of apple it Might be help you

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's built-in since iOS 4 (for UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit):

```
@import AVFoundation;

AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageView.image.size, imageView.bounds);
```

Since frame components may be not round numbers, consider wrapping the call by

```
CGRectIntegral(…)
```

see https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/ for more info.

Comment: My question is "If i have a image(Human wearing cap) ,here i need cap boundaries."

Answer (score 0):

You have already got idea that how to check that two CGRect is overlapping or not. with @Mario's answer.

Question is how you can get image size from imageView which is

```
AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: myImage.size, insideRect: sampleImageView.frame)
```

But one more thing you need to take care about `contains(_:)` or `intersects(_:)` of `CGRect` is that **both should have same superview**. like

**Main( UIView) -> UIImageView**

and

**Main( UIView) -> UIView(that need to be checked)**

If this condition is not applying with your view hierarchy you have options to convert rect  using

1)  `convertRect:fromView:` [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622498-convertrect)

2) `convertRect:toView`   [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convertrect)

Hope it is helpful

Comment: My question is "If i have a image(Human wearing cap) ,here i need cap boundaries."

Comment: @bAthi This is different question. You have to use https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion